# SHA1 Hash Results

Tags: apex, encryption, crypto

I am trying to encryption a string using [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) encryption.
**Test string**

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>
> 2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12 (encryption token)

You can validate this here
http://www.sha1-online.com/

But if I use same string in Salesforce with this code

```
blob hashSHA1 =Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', blob.valueOf('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'));
String hashBase64SHA1 = EncodingUtil.base64encode (hashSHA1);
System.debug (hashBase64SHA1);
```

Then I get the output

> L9ThxnotKPzthJ7hu3bnORuT6xI=

If anyone can let me know what I am doing wrong here or if I need to update anything or the correct method that would be helpful.

Comment: This is a hash, it is **not** encryption.

Comment: One is hex, the other is base64 encoded. If you didn't want base64 encoded output, why did you call the `base64encode` function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You Should use this

```
String shasign = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1',Blob.valueOf(Your String)));
```

*Clarification -:* 
**base64Encode** will simply convert a Blob to an unencoded String representing its normal form. It will not encode the blob in any form just simply return the String.

Whereas
**convertToHex** will return a hexadecimal (base 16) representation of the inputBlob.

Comment: This is correct. To clarify you could maybe add a small description of the difference between `base64encode()` and `convertToHex()`.